# Error in hyperledger chaincode for developers cannot start the network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html .

I'm trying chain-code for developers doc.after finished what it told me about the preparation. I start the network by

> docker-compose -f docker-compose-simple.yaml up

all seems well but meet the question below:

[image]

[image]

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

as you can see i followed all the steps it showed me in the link